# Post-Redirect-Get with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, post-redirect-get, redirect-after-post

How can i implement the [Post-Redirect-Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern with ASP.NET?

A button click performs some processing:

```
<asp:Button id="bbLaunch" OnCommand="bbLaunch_Click" />
```

User clicks the button, the spacecraft is launched, the web-page redisplays. If the user presses F5, they get the warning:

[image]

The solution to the problem is the [Post-Redirect-Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern.

What is the method by which [PRG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) can be implemented in ASP.NET?

---

The question centers around the problems of:

- how can the `<asp:Button>` perform a **`POST`** to a place that isn't its original form?
- what becomes of the **ViewState** when you post to a form that doesn't read view state?
- what becomes of the **ViewState** when you redirect to the "real" aspx web form?
- is **ViewState** fundamentally incompatible with <strike>ASP.net</strike> Post-Redirect-Get?
- is ASP.net fundamentally incompatible with **Post-Redirect--Get**?
- *how* (i.e. what code) do you redirect to the "real" aspx web form?
- *how* (i.e. what url) do you redirect to the "real" aspx web form? A relation question mentions `Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);`
- *when* (i.e. in what event handler) do you redirect to the "real" aspx web form?
- the related questions raise issues of *how* you post form data. There is the implication that HTML *forms* cannot be used - and all form data must be added to the query string. Is this true? If so, why? If not, why not? **Can** a browser put form data in a query string?
- a related question mentions `Server.Transfer`. Using `Server.Transfer` is completely wrong, and in no way solves the Post-Redirect-Get problem (because there is no *Redirect*). Correct?
- what code change has to happen in the `aspx` or `aspx.cs` file to support PRG? Presumably, at the very least, the code must be changed to `post` somewhere besides `MyPage.aspx`.

In other words: **How do you do Post-Redirect-Get in ASP.net?**

**Note**: ASP.net (i.e. not ASP.net MVC)

### See also

- [How do I implement the Post/Redirect/Get pattern in asp.net WebForms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919516/how-do-i-implement-the-post-redirect-get-pattern-in-asp-net-webforms)
- [How do I use the “Post/Redirect/Get” a.k.a. “Redirect after Post” with asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331277/how-do-i-use-the-post-redirect-get-a-k-a-redirect-after-post-with-asp-net)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Typically you would do this by making an aspx web form that uses the querystring to signal which record to load/process.

Let's say you have a page that let's you update some customer information:

```
http://www.mysite.com/customer.aspx
```

You would load the form using an id in the querystring:

```
http://www.mysite.com/customer.aspx?CustomerId=42
```

In the codebehind you would have something like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        int customerId = 0;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["CustomerId"]))
        {
            int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["CustomerId"], out customerId );
        }
        if (customerId == 0) 
        {
            //handle case when no valid customer id was passed in the qs here
        }
        else 
        {
            //load customer details, bind controls etc
            //make sure to handle the case when no customer was found using the id in the qs
        }
    }
}
```

Then somewhere in your page you would have a button that saves the changes. That button would have an OnClick handler in the code behind:

```
protected void SaveClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //save changes to database here

    //Redirect if all went well
    Response.Redirect("http://www.mysite.com/customer.aspx?CustomerId=" 
        + idOfSavedCustomer.ToString());
}
```

That should basically be it. The redirect will cause the browser to issue a new GET request for the url in the Redirect(...). It will load the page, the `if (!IsPostBack)` will run and initialize the page with the new values you just saved in the previous post back.

For this whole process, the traffic between browser and server would look something like this:

```
Browser: GET http://www.mysite.com/customer.aspx?CustomerId=42
Server: 200 (send back some html)

Browser: POST http://www.mysite.com/customer.aspx?CustomerId=42 (post data sent in request)
Server: 302 (point to http://www.mysite.com/customer.aspx?CustomerId=42)

Browser: GET http://www.mysite.com/customer.aspx?CustomerId=42
Server: 200 (send html)
```

In the middle step, the server is basically saying:

*"That post request you sent me, I'm done with that. Now please got to this other page here..."*

The fact the url in fact referrs to the same page is not important.

---

Some musings in response to your bullet point list of questions:

- how can the  perform a POST to a place that isn't its
  original form?

You can do this by setting the `action` attribute on the form, or you can set the `PostBackUrl` on the button.

- what becomes of the ViewState when you post to a form that doesn't
  read view state?

Depends. If you simply post the form to a different page, you can use the <%@ PreviousPageType .../> directive to tell the "new" page where the post came from. This will simplyfy working with the posted data on the new page. See [this link for details](http://aspalliance.com/1440_CrossPage_Postbacks_Made_Easy_with_NET_20.1).

- what becomes of the ViewState when you redirect to the "real" aspx
  web form?

View state is sent in the post request. When redirecting, the browser will load a new page and it will create it's own viestate.

- is ViewState fundamentally incompatible with ASP.net
  Post-Redirect-Get?

Depends on how you look at it. After the redirect the new page will not have access to the viewstate of the page before.

- is ASP.net fundamentally incompatible with Post-Redirect--Get?

No. See example above.

- how (i.e. what code) do you redirect to the "real" aspx web form?

Response.Redirect(url). This will send a response to the browser, telling it to do a new get request.

- when (i.e. in what event handler) do you redirect to the "real" aspx
  web form?

When you have performed all the work necessary to process the post request.

- the related questions raise issues of how you post form data. There
  is the implication that HTML forms cannot be used - and all form data
  must be added to the query string. Is this true? If so, why? If not,
  why not? Can a browser put form data in a query string?

Redirecting a post request is not well supported and should probably be avoided. It can be done (with some browser) by using the http response 307. When doing that, the server effectively tells the browser that "*I will not process you post request, please post it to this other page instead*".

- a related question mentions Server.Transfer. Using Server.Transfer is
  completely wrong, and in no way solves the Post-Redirect-Get problem
  (because there is no Redirect). Correct?

Server.Transfer(...) is something that is taking place on the server side. The browser is not aware of it. Basically a page can use Server.Transfer in order to have som other page do some processing, and that page will be responsible for sending a response back to the browser. But the browser will think that it was the original page the responded.

- what code change has to happen in the aspx or aspx.cs file to support
  PRG? Presumably, at the very least, the code must be changed to post
  somewhere besides MyPage.aspx.

No, a regular post back can be used. The trick is to have one (or a few) specific event handler(s) on the page which does a Repsonse.Redirect after processing the posted data.

Answer (score 7):

Q) how can the  perform a POST to a place that isn't its original form?

A) With PRG, you don't POST to a different page, you post back to the same page (see the diagram on the wikipedia page you linked to.) But the response from that page MUST BE a 30X response (typically a 302.)

Q) what becomes of the ViewState when you post to a form that doesn't read view state?

A) The view state is there when you POST, but there the view state won't be there for the new page you are doing a GET on.

Q) what becomes of the ViewState when you redirect to the "real" aspx web form?

A) Per above, there is no more view state are redirecting to the page.

Q) is ViewState fundamentally incompatible with ASP.net?

A) ViewState is not incompatible with ASP.NET. It is (mostly) useless for P/R/G for rendering the page that you are redirected to.

Q) is ASP.net fundamentally incompatible with Post-Redirect--Get?

A) No - but you can't overly rely on using one page and keeping all your state in viewstate, as per above. That said, ASP.MVC is maps much better to P/R/G

Q) how (i.e. what code) do you redirect to the "real" aspx web form?

A) Response.Redirect("new_page_you_are_redirecting_to.aspx") in the bbLaunch_Click method of old_page_you_are_posting_from.aspx

Q) how (i.e. what url) do you redirect to the "real" aspx web form? A relation question mentions Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);

A) See above

Q) when (i.e. in what event handler) do you redirect to the "real" aspx web form?

A) After you've processed the button press, saved the data to DB (or session, etc), and before you've written anything else to the Response stream.

Q) the related questions raise issues of how you post form data. There is the implication that HTML forms cannot be used - and all form data must be added to the query string. Is this true?

A) No - the button press in ASP.NET WebForms will POST back to the page.

Q) If so, why? If not, why not?

A) It's simpler than this, is why not. Imaging two pages: first_page.asp and second_page.aspx. First_page.aspx has the button on it (along with other ASP.NET web controls, like text boxes, etc that the user has filled out.) When they press the button, a POST is made to first_page.aspx. After processing the the data (which is likely inside viewstate, though this is abstracted away), you redirect the user to second_page.aspx using Response.redirect. Second_page.aspx can display what you want. If you want (or need) to display UI that is similar to what was on first_page.aspx, including the controls and what they inputted, you would want to store that in the session, a cookie, the URL as querystring params, to set those controls on second_page.aspx. (But you may not need to display anything on second_page.aspx that is similar to first_page.aspx - so there is no general rule here.)

Q) Can a browser put form data in a query string?

A) Yes, if you set the method to GET instead of POST. You can't override WebForms to do this, and this isn't required for PRG

Q) a related question mentions Server.Transfer. Using Server.Transfer is completely wrong, and in no way solves the Post-Redirect-Get problem (because there is no Redirect). Correct?

A) Essentially

Q) what code change has to happen in the aspx or aspx.cs file to support PRG? Presumably, at the very least, the code must be changed to post somewhere besides MyPage.aspx.

A) The code should still post back (as mentioned above.) But then Mypage.aspx should re-direct to a new page in the button handler.

Answer (score 5):

The exactly steps of the Post Redirect Get are this one:

[image]

You have the form that you complete with data, and after your valid submit (POST) you insert them to your database, and give them a confirmation id, then you redirect the user to the page with this confirmation id as URL parameter that is used as the (GET) After the redirect every F5-refresh is only read the data and not insert them again.

The code for insert is different than the code that show the confirmation, you can even make them different pages - you can make the same page with read only text boxes.

The redirect is simple the `Responce.Redirect` function of asp.net

After the POST and the making of the redirect the only think that connect you with the previous action is the confirmation code (not the viewstate)

The minus of this method is that is actually is not recognize the refresh, is just make an extra step that make the refresh not inserting again the same data - but needs extra code for the Get data.

The alternative is to recognize the refresh and not make redirect. By recognize the refresh on post back you can avoid inserting the same data with a single message to the user. There are some examples on the internet for that, and I have implement one with success.

One Example: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/319955/How-to-prevent-Re-Post-action-caused-by-pressing-b

Answer (score 5):

The Post-Redirect-Get pattern can be used in Web Forms. I've shown how this can be done by converting the MVC NerdDinner application to Web Forms, http://navigationnerddinner.codeplex.com/ . I've kept the navigation details exactly the same so there are plenty of examples of the PRG pattern.

However, there is another way to avoid the F5/Refresh problem. If you wrap your page in an UpdatePanel (part of ASP.NET Ajax) then all post backs will be converted into partial page requests. This means when F5 is pressed it will only refresh the original GET request (since there haven't been any subsequent POSTs), and so you won't get the warning. (Note, If JavaScript is disabled the warning will still appear).

Comment: Thanks for this great tip! I've been working with WebForms for so long, but when I was currently musing about PRG I totally forgot about using an UpdatePanel instead! This solves the problem of refreshing the page very easily!

Answer (score 4):

You can invoke the [Response.Redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) method to go to another location.

Comment: How do i get to the page that has the `Response.Redirect`?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things that go into this.

1. Set the *action* attribute of the form on the main page (let's call it *LaunchForm.aspx*) equal to the URL of the "proxy" page (*ProxyLaunchForm.aspx*).

   > <form id="form1" runat="server" action="ProxyLaunchForm.aspx" method="POST">
2. (optional) Add a hidden input with the name *redirectUrl* to the form and value the URL that tells *ProxyLaunchForm.aspx* where to redirect once it is finished performing the launch (the R part of PRG).
3. Now on *ProxyLaunchForm.aspx*, the implementation should take place inside the *Page_Load* event handler, because that has access to form post data.  Execute the launch here.
4. Subsequently (also in *Page_Load*), perform the redirect (either using the *redirectUrl* from #2, or simply using the referring page URL):

   > Response.Redirect(Request.Params["redirectUrl"] ?? Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri);

   There's still the matter of the View State.  I think the easiest way to deal with this is to change how the view state gets persisted.  Normally, it is saved into a hidden input element on the page and retrieved on postback (which of course means it would be lost after the redirect due to the stateless nature of HTTP).  However, you can override the methods that ASP.net uses, and have it use the *Session* instead (that way it will still be present even after the PRG proxy action).  So, finally...
5. In *LaunchForm.aspx.cs*, use as the base class a subclassed *Page* that overrides the *SavePageStateToPersistenceMedium* and *LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium* methods to store/retrieve them from the session, rather than from a hidden form field.  See below (and [here's more info on how this works.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx#viewstate_topic10)).

*

```
public class PersistViewStateToSession : Page
{
    protected override void SavePageStateToPersistenceMedium(object viewState)
    {
        // serialize the view state into a base-64 encoded string
        LosFormatter los = new LosFormatter();
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        los.Serialize(writer, viewState);
        // save the string to session
        Session["LaunchViewState"] = writer.ToString();
    }

    protected override object LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium()
    {
       if (!Session["LaunchViewState"] == null)
           return null;
       else
       {
          string sessionString = (string)Session["LaunchViewState"];
          // deserialize the string
          LosFormatter los = new LosFormatter();
          return los.Deserialize(viewStateString);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Item 4 - stashing values in the `session` is very different from the `viewstate` as the session's not persisted (by default).  After 20 mins (by default) or when the server/virtual machine's restarted or recycled.  So,  for those mobile devices which reload the page days later,  you won't have any data. The ViewState stashes the data permanently - or until the page is cleared from the browser.