# Prevent clicking a button after page reload

Tags: asp.net, page-refresh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Post-Redirect-Get with ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381162/post-redirect-get-with-asp-net)

I have a button on my form. Inside the button_click event I insert some data to database. If I click that button and then refresh the page, it seems the button gets clicked again because I find the same data inserted to the database twice. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Please post some relevant code

Comment: Also this is similar q/a: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615403/detect-browser-refresh

Comment: @Aristos, I understand that this is a possible duplicate. But I have to first know what  Post-Redirect-Get is to ask a question containing it. Neither of the posts you referred to have a question similar to mine. That's why I asked this question.

Comment: @MikeJM I am not say anything against you at all (nether vote anything minus), and I understand that you can not locate it, I just give some links try to help you to see possible solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [PRG patern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) to avoid this problem.
When you refresh the page your last request(either get or Post) resubmitted to the server again.

**Solution**: In the click event use this at the last

```
  Response.Redirect(@"~\page.aspx");
```

Answer (score 1):

after insert you can redirect to the same page using `Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)`

this will prevent the problem

Comment: What you have type here is work, but the user did not understand nether know if the data is final insert by just reload the page.