# Difference in Refreshing?

Tags: asp.net, post, refresh

In a Browser, Is there any difference between **Pressing F5** and **Pressing Enter** after keeping the cursor in the Address Bar ?....If yes just tell me, it will be helpful for me to develop website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there are totally different.

When you press **F5 the browser refresh** the page vs, when you press **Enter on the url the browser get the page**.

Meaning that with the F5 if the last action was a post, the browser re-post the data, when you press enter, everything that you have done, or enter to the page lost, any data enter, any post back with the enter are lost.

There is also the **Shift + F5** that force the browser to reload/refress the page after clear the cache for this one. On google chrome, if you have open the tools, and you click more than 3 seconds on the f5 opens a menu with additional options.

You may also find intresting that posts : [Post-Redirect-Get with ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381162/post-redirect-get-with-asp-net) and  [Detect browser refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615403/detect-browser-refresh/6615430#6615430)