# onclick function being called when page loads

Tags: c#, asp.net, onclick

I am new to ASP/C# programming:

I have an `asp:button` created as follows:

```
<asp:button
    ID="CreateItem"
    ClientIDMode="Static"
    OnClick="btnSave_Click"
    runat="server"
    Text="SAVE">
</asp:button>
```

In the code behind, I have the following:

```
btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Code here to create an Item    
}
```

I noticed that when I refresh the page after clicking my button, this function is being called. To verify, I ran the debugger and set a breakpoint inside the `btnSave_Click` function and verified that it was indeed going inside the function when I refresh my page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you refresh after clicking the button?

Comment: @Oded yes. I was just about to edit that into my post

Comment: That's why. The browser is trying to recreate the same request, so the server understands it to be a request that triggers the button click. You need to go to the address bar and press enter for a new request to be made.

Comment: Does this occur on the very first load of the page, or only when pressing refresh?

Comment: Is `btnSave_Click` being referenced anywhere else in your code behind? Perhaps in the `Page_Load`?

Comment: @Oded is there a way to clear the request when the user refreshes or is this a non-issue?

Comment: It can't be done on the browser. The normal way to deal with this is the [PRG pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) (user posts, server redirects (after processing) to a different page that the browser then gets)t

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's being called on a page refresh after you clicked the button because the original button click caused the form to be posted. When you refresh the page after that, the browser is simply re-posting the form data and thus calling the call-back function again.

To avoid this you can simply enter the url or highlight the url in the address bar and press enter and it will treat it as a page load.

**EDIT**: Didn't fully understand what you were asking. To avoid having this happen when a user clicks refresh you can do as Oded mentioned in the comments and do a re-direct after posting: [Post-Redirect-Get with ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381162/post-redirect-get-with-asp-net)

From the link:

```
protected void SaveClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //save changes to database here

    //Redirect if all went well
    Response.Redirect("~/yourpage.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [PRG patern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) to avoid this problem. When you refresh the page your last request(either get or Post) resubmitted to the server again.

Solution: In the click event use Response.Redirect after your code

```
btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Code here to create an Item   
    Response.Redirect(@"~\page.aspx"); 
}
```