# Post redirect get solution for the double submit prevention

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `register.aspx` which takes some information from user and stores it in the database. However, I cannot solve the double submit  problem when user refreshes the page. Here is my `registration.aspx` file:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
     <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

     <asp:Button ID="btnRegister" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="RegisterUser" />

     <asp:Label ID="lblErrorMessage" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</form>
```

And here is the `registration.aspx.cs` file:

```
protected void RegisterUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtUserName.Text.Length < 3)
    {
        lblErrorMessage.Text = "username should be minimum 3 characters, try again.";
    }
}
```

However, I try to test it using my browser, chrome. When I use the text "a" for the username, it goes into the `RegisterUser` function and shows the error message. But sadly, when I try to refresh the page it asks for resubmission while I was expecting to refresh without any problem:

[image]

I tried using `Response.Redirect` and it didn't work either.

Comment: The `Response.Redirect` will done the work, you probably did not apply it correctly.

Comment: @Aristos, can you give the correct version of using `Response.Redirect` please?

Comment: @zagy If you want you can redirect the page after submit. 

But, I think  it is common behaviour of form. You can see same behaviour of form on many site like gmail login page.

Comment: @zagy No, I prefer you write the non working code. Also see that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381162/post-redirect-get-with-asp-net

Comment: @Aristos I tried adding the line, `Response.Redirect("register.aspx")`  to `RegisterUser` and it didn't work. What was your solution? PS: I read the mentioned `SO` question, i couldn't understand it.

Comment: @zagy Try to add a random url parameter at the end to force to load it again and not get it from the cache.

Comment: @Aristos I don't want to make my url looks dirty. Is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: @zagy Disable the client cache by adding headers.

Comment: @Aristos I disabled client cache using `Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);` still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried an easy way for you using UpdatePanel and Template:

change the code in your main page like this:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" >

  <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server"><ContentTemplate>
     <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
     <asp:Button ID="btnRegister" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="RegisterUser" />
     <asp:Label ID="lblErrorMessage" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
     <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
     </asp:ScriptManager>
     </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```

I think that will solve your problem in an easier way. 
Let me know if you have any problem with it.

Comment: Yes but we use SSL for the page (RegisteringUsers.aspx). because it connects to database.

Comment: and if you want to create more secure session. that's another story..
you need to use (SessionFacade) class.

Comment: So, basically, you actually use another `.aspx` file rather than using just another function like my `RegisterUser()` function to prevent this error message?

Comment: Let's think about it in this way... 
If you fill the information and submitting it in the same page... you will probably get the resend message if someoen refresh the page.
but what we do is that after submitting the information...the user will be directed to another page (where the RegisterUser()) function is in...and again redirected to the Register.aspx page or anyother pages.

Comment: I will try to write a simple code for you. just give me 5 min

Comment: That would be wonderful, I was still trying to understand it.

Comment: I don't think I need to use `UpdatePanel`. It may reduce the performance.

Comment: UpdatePanel will not change anything. it's just a partial update on your page.

Comment: I have no idea about that. Visual studio 2012 is the latest version when you wopen a new website template. they used UpdatePanel in every webpages by default...

Answer (score 0):

please set causesvalidation="false" in your TextBox and button control

for try below code

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" CausesValidation="false" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="btnRegister"  CausesValidation="false" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="RegisterUser" />
```