# Textbox remembers its data on page refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 textbox on my page and a Button. When I click on a button, the text from the textbox is emailed. But, then when i refresh the page and no content is there, then also i get an email.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox2.Text))
    {
           //email logic
           TextBox1.Text = "";
           TextBox2.Text = "";

    }

    else
    {
    //do nothing
    }
 }
```

Here, on clicking the button, i get an email but then when i refresh the page, even though there is no data, then also it goes inside the loop and i get an email.

How do i stop this ?

Comment: Post data are part of request, all values are stored in it and after you hit F5, you are resending request not creating new one. That is a reason why you are getting new email.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Post-Redirect-Get with ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381162/post-redirect-get-with-asp-net)

Comment: You may disable ViewState in your page directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following in your `Page_Load` event and keep your TextBoxes and Button in an `<asp:UpdatePanel>`. Then the page will not ask to re-submit each time you refresh the page.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = string.Empty;
        TextBox2.Text = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Keep the controls within an UpdatePanel as follows

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" >
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Send mail" onclick="Button1_Click" />            
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: what do you mean by keeping in <asp:UpdatePanel> ??

Comment: Sorry, keep your controls in an UpdatePanel

Comment: Awesome, it worked. But can you explain me why it worked, when i kept the control in update panel ?

Comment: Because it's using Ajax and does a partial update. And, Script manager takes care of the page refresh issue you faced before. It only submits the form once how many time you refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the the POST > Redirect > GET pattern. Here is explanation [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381162/post-redirect-get-with-asp-net)